# Connect Firebird database to C++

Tags: c++, firebird

I was told to write a program that has read/write access to its own Firebird database. I never worked with Firebird before and the program is supposed to run without requireing Firebird to be installed!

- Do I have to install Firebird in order to generate the programm?
- Is there anything I need to do in order to run the program on a computer that does not have Firebird installed?
- How can I connect Firebird to C++ and execute queries?

I never worked with databases using C++ before and I'm not a computer scientist, so I would really appreciate answers that don't assume too much background knowledge.

Comment: Your question is way too broad. You might want to consider asking it on the firebird-support mailinglist instead.

Comment: `without requireing Firebird to be installed!` - maybe you are expected to use Firebird Embedded. `How can I connect Firebird to C++ ` - you do not, you connect your C program to Firebird. You can use Firebird API directly or use any database access libraries, like IBPP or anything other